# VBA - Power Point - Wrap text in Shape programmatically

Tags: vb.net, vba, powerpoint

I have been working on a small hack around with Power Point to automatically create a Text Box Shape with some preset effect in which the text is dynamically fetched from clipboard. I have quiet a bit of a problem here, the functionality works fine with the following VB script with macros.

```
Sub ReadFromFile()

' CLIPBOARD
Dim MyData As DataObject
Dim strClip As String

' CLIPBOARD
Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.GetFromClipboard
strClip = MyData.GetText

Set activeDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)


 With activeDocument
        'Set QASlide = .Slides.Add(Index:=.Slides.Count + 0, Layout:=ppLayoutBlank)

        activeDocument.Shapes.AddTextEffect PresetTextEffect:=msoTextEffect28, _
        Text:=strClip, _
        FontName:="Garde Gothic", FontSize:=44, FontBold:=msoTrue, _
        FontItalic:=msoFalse, Left:=25, Top:=25

        With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        .Width = 200
        .Height = 300
        End With

 End With

End Sub
```

**Can some one help me in providing the script for wrapping the text inside the shape which has a defined width and height as in the code above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you right but does adding `.TextFrame.WordWrap = msoTrue` to the block below solve your problem?

```
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
    .Width = 200
    .Height = 300
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
.Shapes(.Shapes.Count).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strClip
```

You can set it in the same `With` that you are setting the height and width

Answer (score 0):

If you want text to wrap within a shape, you'll have to use something other than a texteffect shape.